# Unable to add TextBox line to list<string>

Tags: c#, winforms

I have been working on a windows from application abd I seem to have run into a problem where I am getting `Index as out of rang of array` when trying to add a text box line to a list:

My current code is as follows:

```
 if (NameTB.Lines.Count() > 0)
                for (int i = 1; 1 <= NameTB.Lines.Count(); i++)
                    nameList.Add(NameTB.Lines[i].Replace(Environment.NewLine, "").Trim());
```

I have also tried this:

```
    if (NameTB.Lines.Length > 0)
        for (int i = 1; 1 <= NameTB.Lines.Length; i++)
            nameList.Add(NameTB.Text[i - 1].ToString().Replace(Environment.NewLine, "").Trim());
```

and

```
        if (NameTB.Lines.Count() > 0)
            for (int i = 1; 1 <= NameTB.Lines.Count(); i++)
                nameList.Add(Convert.ToString(i).Replace(Environment.NewLine, "").Trim());
```

Also though the last example does not give the index error but gets stuck in a loop. I have done something like this before but using `WPF` and `TextBox.GetLineText` but to sure how to achive the same thing in `Winforms`

Comment: In `for` loop condition `1 <= NameTB.Lines.Count` will always return `true` - so you end up with infinite loop

Comment: You can get all lines  by `var lines = NameTB.Text.Split(Environment.NewLine).Select(line => line.Trim()).ToArray();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
if (NameTB.Lines.Count() > 0)
    for (int i = 0; i < NameTB.Lines.Count(); i++) //or i <= NameTB.Lines.Count() - 1
        nameList.Add(NameTB.Lines[i].Replace(Environment.NewLine, "").Trim());
```

Indexing in c# are 0-based, so you need to start from `0` (of course if you don't want to start from second element).

**Of course** your infinite loop and `IndexOutOfRangeException` problems caused by `1 <= NameTB.Lines.Count();` condition, your `i` increasing endlessly, but `NameTB.Lines` has limited amount of elements, so  you should use `i` instead of `1`.

But only changing `1` to `i` will not solve your problem, because elements count in any array/collection is ***always*** bigger than the last element's index, so you need to change

```
i <= NameTB.Lines.Count();
```

to

```
i < NameTB.Lines.Count(); //or i <= NameTB.Lines.Count() - 1;
```

Comment: you really should mention that the error comes about, because the cacel condition in OP's for loop is a comparison of `Count` with the number `1` and not the indexing variable.

Comment: " it can cause an infinite loop, but it will never throw IndexOutOfRangeException" Yes, this is exactly what the result of an endless incrementation of `i` will be. if the loop never stops, `i` will be at some point larger than `Count`

Comment: I am downvoting, because your answer does not address the core of the problem. The core is the cancel condition of the loop, not the starting value. Your post has a working code, but you failed to explain why the problem arose in the first place

Comment: Might be worth noticing the `if` isn't necessary as it is contained in the *continue condition* of the `for` loop

Answer (score 1):

```
1 <= NameTB.Lines.Count();
```

Isnt that always true, as you dont change the Count of the Lines (and you shouldnt eitherway)?

I guess you want to loop until

```
i < NameTB.Lines.Count();
```

And want to start at 0, as the first index in an array is 0

Comment: In this case he will also get `IndexOutOfRangeException`, because of `<=` (Only second version will work)

Answer (score 1):

Note that arrays are zero-based, and your second argument seems creating an infinite loop which exceeds the maximum array index of `Lines`. The correct for-loop construction should be like this:

```
if (NameTB.Lines.Count() > 0) 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < NameTB.Lines.Count(); i++)
    {
        nameList.Add(NameTB.Lines[i].Replace(Environment.NewLine, "").Trim());
    }
}
```

See also:

[What is an IndexOutOfRangeException / ArgumentOutOfRangeException and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20940979/what-is-an-indexoutofrangeexception-argumentoutofrangeexception-and-how-do-i-f)

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
if (NameTB.Lines.Count() > 0)
                for (int i = 1; i <= NameTB.Lines.Count() - 1; i++)
                    nameList.Add(NameTB.Lines[i-1].Replace(Environment.NewLine, "").Trim());
```

Comment: You should explain your answer. Also, I generally use `i < [..].Count()` instead of `i <= [..].Count() - 1` which seems more messy to me.

Comment: Yeah, you can use Count() or Count() - 1. I just want to make it is similar as the original code, so you can see the different. ;)